# Unable to run powershell.exe and execute ps1 file using Invoke-WmiMethod when user is not logged in using remote desktop

Tags: java, powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to execute a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script `exec.ps1` which is in my remote machine. I am using below command from my [java](/questions/tagged/java) code using [`winrm4j`](https://github.com/cloudsoft/winrm4j) library.

```
$execProc = Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -name create -argumentlist 'powershell -file "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\exec.ps1"';Write-Output $execProc.ProcessId | Out-File 'C:\Users\pid.txt'
```

my exec.ps1 file content is below

```
cd 'C:\Users\Administrator\'
& C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\command.ps1  2> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\error.txt 1> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\logs.txt
Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE | Out-File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\status.txt'
```

command.ps1 content is below.

```
. 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\addn.ps1'
Get-Date
```

and addn.ps1 content is below

```
$EXECUTION_FOLDER='C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\'
$SCRIPT_RESPONSE_FILE='C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\powershell_script\rsp.txt'
```

It works as long as the user is logged in using *Remote Desktop Protocol* (RDP). However when the user is logged out from RDP the PowerShell process keeps running forever without any result.

I tried using Invoke-CimMethod but same result.

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: I'd guess something you're doing, maybe powershell or something in that script, can't run completely headlessly and requires a desktop session. I'm not sure how to track that down.

Comment: @Rup i have added the content of my script file which i am executing.